# Suppress non-trivially useless warning "control may reach end of non-void function"

Tags: c++, warnings, control-flow

This is more of a convenience issue than anything, but I'd like to know if there's any way I could suppress the warning:

> control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

for specific cases where I *know* that there's no issue with the code. I have some helper functions in my codebase for throwing exceptions, and for code like this:

```
int foo(int i) {
    if (i > 10) {
        return i*10;
    }
    else {
        Exception::throwExcept(MyCustomException("Error: i not in the accepted range"));
    }
}
```

I know that it will either return, or throw, no matter what. Thus the warning is pretty useless in my eyes, it's just that the compiler can't determine that the control flow path will actually end up throwing.

I would still want to see this warning pop-up for cases where it is actually a sign that the code is wrong (i.e. with a path that does not return or throw).

Would that be possible in a portable way?

EDIT: Forgot to add the compiler I'm using,

> Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41)

Comment: @Holt It doesn't change anything, with or without the `else`.

Comment: Does it still warn if you remove the pointless `else`?

Comment: `return Exception::throwExcept(MyCustomException("Error: i not in the accepted range")), 0`?

Comment: @Holt did you replace ``Exception::throwExcept(MyCustomException(...))`` by a throw statement ? If you did this issue might come from the fact that that compiler can't deduce that the function will always throw.

Comment: @JBL I'll write that up then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler cannot figure out that `Exception::throwExcept()` will not return. There are two solutions here. One is to tell the compiler that, i.e.

```
struct Exception
{
    [[noreturn]] static void throwExcept(SomeType const&);
};
```

(clang's `-Wmissing-noreturn`, which is included in `-Weverything`, will warn if above function could be declared `[[noreturn]]` but isn't) or re-arrange the function as

```
int foo(int i) {
    if (!(i>10))
        Exception::throwExcept(MyCustomException("Error: i not in the accepted range"));

    return i*10;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Marking the `Exception::throwExcept` function `[[noreturn]]` should help the compiler figure out that it will, in fact, not return.

Comment: In MSVC, that would be `__declspec(noreturn)`

Comment: @CodyGray Actually, latest MSVC versions accept `[[ noreturn ]]` (don't know from which version though... ).

Comment: Well, that may be (I haven't verified support for these on recent versions), but the asker indicated in a comment to another answer that the whole reason he had a wrapper function to throw exceptions was he was using `std::nested_exception`, and that wasn't supported by his version of MSVC, so he needed to choose an appropriate implementation depending on the toolchain. That suggests his version of MSVC will *not* support C++11 attributes.

Comment: @Holt From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) looks like 2015 was the first version.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way to suppress the error is to use the comma operator in a return statement.  If you use

```
return Exception::throwExcept(MyCustomException("Error: i not in the accepted range")), 0;
```

The compiler will see a return statement, but it will never actualy execute as

```
Exception::throwExcept(MyCustomException("Error: i not in the accepted range"))
```

Will throw before it can return 0.

Comment: this hack is not necessary and hard to read/understand. It's bad practice.

Comment: It's true that it would be less readable and more confusing than some of the other answers. :|

Comment: @Walter I agree but I'll leve it up as an alternative.  Your answer is a lot better (I like the simple change around the lines of code) and has my vote.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your compiler can't see inside `Exception::throwExcept` to know that it always throws an exception out.

Help the compiler with with a raw C++ exception `throw` as the last line of your function: `throw std::exception("Just to help the compiler know to not warn here");` This won't hurt performance since the code and never be executed.

Comment: Unfortunately I would still like to use my `throwExcept` function. Long story short, I'm using nested exceptions, but my build is cross-platform and with a MSVC version that doesn't support them. So until it'll be possible to upgrade the MSVC version, I need that function to choose between `std::nested_exception` and a reimplementation of these.

Comment: @JBL Mark meant not to change your `throwExcept`, but to *add* a line `throw "something";` as the last line (which will never be reached).